# How to I install openmpi 3.1.6-1 in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, openmpi

In Cygwin, I'm attempting to install openmpi 3.1.6-1. Unfortunately, I can only find newer versions of 4.1.0-1 and 4.0.5-1, not the one I'm seeking for. I went to the website https://www-lb.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v3.1/ and discovered the openmpi 3.1.6-1 version.

Now, how do I go about installing it from this website? or is there a different option?

Answer (score 0):

Openmpi 3.1.x is binary compatible with 4.x

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-May/009518.html
https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2021-November/010320.html

Both have the same shared libraries

```
 libopenmpi40
 libopenmpifh40
 libopenmpiusef08_40
 libopenmpiusetkr40
```

Why do you think you absolutely need 3.1.6 ?